# Rename class members by inheriting class in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, rename, alias

I would like to "rename" some members of my class `ofVec4f`.

I know it's impossible in strict C++ but could I create a new class that inherits from my class and declare new members which are aliases or pointers to the original members?

I tried the following:

```
class ofVec4fGraph : public ofVec4f {

    public :
        float& minX;
        float& maxX;
        float& minY;
        float& maxY;

        ofVec4fGraph(float _minX,float _maxX, float _minY, float _maxY )
                    : minX(_minX), maxX(_maxX), minY(_minY), maxY(_maxY)
                    { ofVec4f(_minX, _maxX, _minY, _maxY); };

    };
```

Comment: You should call base constructor in initialization list: ...`) : ofVec4f(_minX, _maxX, _minY, _maxY), `...

Comment: In bracket is the wrong place to do that ?

Comment: it would be ok in Java, but in C++ your code is only creating on stack temporary value of type ofVec4f.

Comment: Note that each reference will take `sizeof(float*)` more bytes, and accessing them will require dereferencing a pointer. Consider using member function if possible - there's no performance penalty, compilers are smart enough to inline the functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class should be:

```
class ofVec4fGraph : public ofVec4f {
public :
  float& minX;
  float& maxX;
  float& minY;
  float& maxY;

  ofVec4fGraph(float _minX,float _maxX, float _minY, float _maxY )
                    : ofVec4f(_minX, _maxX, _minY, _maxY), minX(x), maxX(y), minY(z), maxY(w)
     {};

};
```

*Constructor chaining* is not possible in `C++`. You use initializer list to initialize base class.

You can now use this as:

```
ofVec4fGraph obj;
fun1(obj.x, obj.y);
fun2(obj.maxX, obj.minY);
```

Comment: Can I do it with struct? Will it be Plain Old Data?

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work well with POD :(. I tested that that class contains additional 4 bytes pointer for each reference - visual studio.

Answer (score 5):

I think this may be what you want.

```
#include <iostream>

class CBase
{
public:
    CBase() : a(0), b(0), c(0) {}
    CBase(int aa, int bb, int cc) : a(aa), b(bb), c(cc) {}
    int a, b, c;
};

class CInterface
{
public:
    CInterface(CBase &b) 
    : base(b), x(b.a), y(b.b), z(b.c) 
    {
    }
    int &x, &y, &z;
private:
    CBase &base;
};

int main() 
{
    CBase      base(1, 2, 3);
    CInterface iface(base);

    std::cout << iface.x << ' ' << iface.y << ' ' << iface.z << std::endl;
    std::cout << base.a << ' ' << base.b << ' ' << base.c << std::endl;

    iface.x = 99;
    base.c = 88;

    std::cout << iface.x << ' ' << iface.y << ' ' << iface.z << std::endl;
    std::cout << base.a << ' ' << base.b << ' ' << base.c << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Is not à job for inherited class ?
```

Not necessarily.

[Proper Inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/proper-inheritance.html) dictates that you only inherit **publicly** when the *derived class* is substitutable for *base class*. In this case you are **implementing derived class in terms of** base class, here the preferred approach is to use [private inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/private-inheritance.html), or yet better [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition). And [composition is better than inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). You should either use the approach described by @Michael J, or use private inheritance.

```
class Base { protected: int x; };
class Derived: private Base { 
 public:
  int getValue(){ return x;} // name the method whatever you like.
};
```

Also learn [why public data member is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399929/should-i-use-public-or-private-variables)

Comment: My class, ofVec4f, from openFrameworks main.h header as his member already in public