# Reference could be pointing struct's members in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, reference

Could we create a structure that contains some values and the reference that is pointing to the values in the same structure? My idea is to make the alias. So I can call struct members in different way !

```
struct Size4
{    
    float x, y;
    float z, w;

    float &minX, &maxX, &minY, &maxY;

    Size4(float _x, float _y, float _z, float _w) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), w(_w),
        minX(x), maxY(y), minY(z), maxY(w)
    {
    }

};
```

---

Thank you all.

NB: I did it with the pointer, but now when I'm trying to call `Size4.minX()` I'm getting the address, but not the value.

```
struct Size4
{    
    float x, y;
    float z, w;

    float *minX, *maxX, *minY, *maxY;

    Size4(float _x, float _y, float _z, float _w) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), w(_w),
        minX(&x), maxX(&y), minY(&y), maxY(&w)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes you can. However the references cannot be reassigned so I don't see much use. What are you trying to accomplish, and have you learned about [pointers to members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670734/c-pointer-to-class-data-member)?

Comment: thanks for the pointer to members link, but with this solution i can access value by adding resolve addresse opertator (*).

Comment: I want to make it transparent.

Size4 size(5,5,5,5);

size.minX; and size.x; returning the same value...

Comment: Well, the point is, you can have these references.

Comment: Just be warned that space must be allocated for the references in the object. So the size of the object will grow as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to make it transparent. Size4 size(5,5,5,5); size.minX; and size.x; returning the same value..."

You can do it like this. However, I suggest you use a `class`.

```
using namespace std;
struct Size4
{
    float x, y;
    float z, w;

    float *minX, *maxX, *minY, *maxY;

    Size4(float _x, float _y, float _z, float _w) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), w(_w),
        minX(&x), maxX(&y), minY(&y), maxY(&w)
    {
    }
};

int main() {
  Size4 s(1,2,3,4);
  std::cout << *(s.minX) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Or you could add this method in your `struct`

```
float getX() {
  return *minX;
}
```

and access it like this:

```
std::cout << s.getX() << std::endl;
```

However, a `class` would provide better enclosure. Private data members and the get-er function to access the `minX`.

[EDIT]

Using a `class` is simple like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Size4
{
 private:
  // these are the private data members of the class
    float x, y;
    float z, w;

    float *minX, *maxX, *minY, *maxY;

 public:
  // these are the public methods of the class
    Size4(float _x, float _y, float _z, float _w) : x(_x), y(_y), z(_z), w(_w),
        minX(&x), maxX(&y), minY(&y), maxY(&w)
    {
    }

    float getX() {
      return *minX;
    }
};

int main() {
  Size4 s(1,2,3,4);
  std::cout << s.getX() << std::endl;
  // std::cout << *(s.minX) << std::endl; <-- error: ‘float* Size4::minX’ is private
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't show how to use a class, it just rehashes the OP's own pointer use case within the struct.

Comment: i asked a question near from this one few days earlier : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23678523/rename-member-by-inherit-class-in-c

couldn't i do the same thing in struct ?

Comment: @dsimonet I updated my answer with a class usage! Why you want to rename a member of a class?

Comment: To make my code a be more readable. And because I'm a beginner and some time i want to make simple thinks and lost a lot of time cause i don't know how to do or if it's possible !

Comment: The question you linked has already an answer that you already accepted. I want to help, but I do not know what am I asked. Didn't my answer answered your original question here? @dsimonet

Comment: Yes your question give me a solution. But not what I'm exactly looking for. No matter. Thanks you a lot for your time :-)

Comment: Damn you can not chat, since you have only 5 rep. I will upvote your question so that you can chat in the future. If I can help you more, let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take your value using the dereferencing operator: `*(size4.minx)`

A little example:

```
Size4 sz(11, 2, 3, 4);
printf("%f, %f, %f, %f", *sz.minX, *sz.maxX, *sz.minY, *sz.maxY);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but dereferencing is exactly what I'm avoiding to do. I'm trying to make it transparent. If i can't i'll make class with get and set methods.

Comment: As for me, the class with setters and getters will be better.