# Keeping two bool class members with opposite values

Tags: c++, class, c++11

I'm planning to have two bool class members (`m_alive` & `m_dead`) so that their values are always opposite ones. This might seem something stupid (in fact, it may just be stupid), but as you can see in the code below, but what I really look for is to have a clearer way to check the object status depending of the circumstances, and it would be useful not having to type `!m_alive` or `!m_dead`.
So, yeah, I don't really need both members but I can't think of an easier way of doing this.

The first idea that came to my mind is to create a function that changes the state of one of them if the other one changes too, but I'm pretty sure there needs to be a simpler, easier and faster way of keeping each one with it's correct value.

AFAIK, it's not possible to do it with `define`'s since there would be as many of them as different objects I plan to create and doesn't seem practical.

```
#define object1.m_death= !object1.m_alive;
#define object2.m_death= !object2.m_alive;
// ...
```

So here you have the main idea of having both members:

```
class myclass
{
    public:
    // (...)
    private:
        bool m_alive;
        bool m_death;   // Always !m_alive
};

int main()
{
    myclass myobject;
    // (...)
    if (myobject.m_dead)
    //...
    if (myobject.m_alive)   // clearer than !myobject.m_dead()
    // ...
}
```

Any suggestions of how-to keep'em updated is welcome, as well as any other ways of implementing my idea. Thanks in advance!

Eduardo

PD: While re-reading my question, enumerated types have just came to my mind.

It would emply checking `myobject.m_status==dead` or `myobject.m_status==alive`, being `dead` and `alive` possible values of dead_or_alive enum-type class member `dead_or_alive m_status`.

Could this be a nicer approach to what I'm seeking, despite being a bit longer syntax?

---

**Final edit**:

Thanks to all who commented and answered. Here's the solution I've finally adopted:

```
enum Piece_status:bool{     dead= false,    alive= true};

class Piece
{
    public:
        bool isAlive() const    {return  m_status;}
        bool isDead()  const    {return !m_status;}
    protected:      
        Piece_status        m_status;   // dead=false, alive=true
};
```

Comment: They are private. So you code won't compile. And you should add a query to your class instead of adding redundant fields. `myobject.is_dead()` or `myobject.is_alive()` can both be implemented in terms of a single `bool`.

Comment: It's redundant and not really needed. `!myobject.m_dead` is just as clear as `myobject.m_alive`.

Comment: two methods: is_alive is_dead and base its implementation in your bool

Comment: It is a good idea to to keep member variables as private; however, you should give them access by `set` and `get` functions which must be `public`.

Comment: @macroland If you have a public getter and a public setter, it's basically a public variable.

Comment: @macroland - Class member functions should encapsulate behavior. An accessor pair isn't behavior encapsulated. It's a cumbersome way to make an aggregate.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I guess this is a nice read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399929/should-i-use-public-or-private-variables

Comment: You're right, @StoryTeller. Thanks everyone for the comments!

Comment: There are 2 hard problems in computer programming.  Cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors.  Your choice of two variables leads you to having a "cache" of the value (am I alive or dead?) in two spots.  Don't make hard problems for yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class myclass
{
    public:
        bool isAlive() const { return m_alive; }
        bool isDead() const { return !m_alive; }
    private:
        bool m_alive;
};

int main()
{
    myclass myobject;
    // (...)
    if (myobject.isDead())
    //...
    if (myobject.isAlive())
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'd make those member functions `const`

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to violate the ["Single Source of Truth"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/317136/98845) best practice, by keeping 2 copies of the same information.

If you're looking for clarity (and you don't find `if(m_alive)` and `if(!m_alive)` clear enough) then add custom getters to `myclass`:

```
bool isAlive() const { return m_alive; }
bool isDead() const { return !m_alive; }
```

Comment: Nice to know the name of the best practice so that not to be tempted to violating it again, thanks! And also for the answer, just what I was loooking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this by using a setter for changing the variables:

```
// optional setters
void setDead() { setDead(true); }
void setAlive() { setDead(false); }

// main setter
void setDead(bool isDead) {
    m_alive = !(m_dead = isDead);
}
```